# Characterization of the Scheepers property by Scheepers game

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

$\Omega$: The collection of all [$\omega$-covers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) of a space $X$. An open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is said to be $\omega$-cover if $X\notin\mathcal U$ and for each finite $F\subseteq X$ there exists a $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $F\subseteq U$.

1. A space $X$ is said to have the [Menger property](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ covers $X$.
2. A space $X$ is said to have the [Scheepers property](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}\in\Omega$ or $\cup\mathcal V_n=X$ for some $n$.

The infinitely long games correponding to the Menger and Scheepers properties are defined as follows.

1. The [Menger game](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) on $X$ is played as follows. Players ONE and TWO play an inning for each positive integer $n$. In the $n$th inning ONE chooses an open cover $\mathcal U_n$ of $X$ and TWO responds by selecting a finite subset $\mathcal V_n$ of $\mathcal U_n$. TWO wins the play $\mathcal U_1,\mathcal V_1,\dotsc,\mathcal U_n,\mathcal V_n,\dotsc$ if $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ covers $X$; otherwise ONE wins.
2. The [Scheepers game](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) on $X$ is played as follows. Players ONE and TWO play an inning for each positive integer $n$. In the $n$th inning ONE chooses an open cover $\mathcal U_n$ of $X$ and TWO responds by selecting a finite subset $\mathcal V_n$ of $\mathcal U_n$. TWO wins the play $\mathcal U_1,\mathcal V_1,\dotsc,\mathcal U_n,\mathcal V_n,\dotsc$ if $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}\in\Omega$ or $\cup\mathcal V_n=X$ for some $n$; otherwise ONE wins.

It is well known that a space $X$ has the Menger property if and only if ONE does not have a winning strategy in the Menger game on $X$ (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674)). We try to prove a similar result for the Scheepers game, but we fail. Does a similar result hold for the Scheepers game?

Answer (score 3):

The theorem you are looking for is a special case of Theorem 6 of the paper [Partition relations for Hurewicz-type selection hypotheses](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864108003039). The needed definitions in the following general theorem are provided in the linked paper.

[image]

The statement is slightly different, but the proof shows the equivalence to what you look for (such equivalences are routine, in any case).

Comment: Look at the paper. What you look for is the case B=Omega